# Gradations between Skim and Contemplate?

Tags: verbs

I'd imagine there is a range of words to describe the spectrum of levels of cares between *skim* and *contemplate*. What are those words?

That is, what are the appropriate words to fill in the blank spaces beween these two words:

1. *skim*: (v) [To read or glance through (a book, for example) quickly or superficially.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/skim)
2. ...
3. ...
4. ...
5. *contemplate* (v) [To consider carefully and at length; meditate on or ponder](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/contemplate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. **Skim** - [to read, study, or examine superficially and rapidly; especially:  to glance through (as a book) for the chief ideas or the plot](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/skim), from *"to remove (as film or scum) from the surface of a liquid"* which is a superficial act.
> 2. **Browse** - [to look over or through an aggregate of things casually especially in search of something of interest](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/browse), very similar to skim, but with the intention of finding some useful information.
> 3. **Consider** [to think carefully about or ponder on](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/consider) or [to think of especially with regard to taking some action; to take into account](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/consider)
> 4. **Study** -[careful or extended consideration](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/study), very similar to contemplate (also [a state of contemplation](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/study))
> 5. **Contemplate** - [to view or consider with continued attention](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contemplate), ultimately [to view as likely or probable or as an end or intention](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contemplate).

Remember it depends what context you are using these in, and there are probably more fine graduations depending on what you want to mean.

Comment: 'Peruse' is notoriously ambiguous.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth how so? what else would you suggest?

Comment: You should add authoritative references to your answer. Checking in a dictionary would almost certainly have thrown up the two conflicting usages. See [Does the word 'peruse' have a single meaning of attentive reading or double, contradicting meanings ... ?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/116016/does-the-word-peruse-have-a-single-meaning-of-attentive-reading-or-double/116029#116029). (If these **are** [partial-] quotes, the sources need attribution.) / I'm not saying your answer is wrong (which is why I've not downvoted), merely that 'peruse' is an awkward ...

Comment: customer (and that your answer needs supporting references).

Comment: Okay, will do.  So peruse depends on what context it's used in? I should add that there's no definite order to graduations between skim and contemplate.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth better?  there's quite a gap between browse and consider, if you have any suggestions.

Comment: The intended meaning of 'peruse' sadly can't even be deduced from context on some occasions. / I'd say most people would just use 'read' to express 2.5, but that's even more ambiguous.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - read would be ambiguous in this situation since it's unclear whether the OP is talking about reading or thinking.